# MOSFET logic gates: Putting the pieces together

Tags: mosfet, logic-gates

So I got this problem.

[image]

And I know MOSFETs...Sort of.

So the area in red is a NAND gate and the area in blue is an Inverter...I think?
So I know what those two pieces are, now how do those connect? Let alone what the other MOSFETs function as. So as the title says I can't "Put the pieces together".

And I know you can't give answers to homework problems. So if you can please give me some breadcrumbs to how these pieces come together, it would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I tried the suggestion in the comments and I got  `0001`. 
I saw that `C` is always 1 so I can treat it as a straight wire (correct me if I'm wrong). I thought if `D` or `E` is one then the MOSFET without the label would treated as a wire and `A`,`B` or `C` would short circuit, I thought the only way is if `D` and `E` are both 0. 
What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT 2:**

I am now getting `1001`.

Comment: I wouldn't immediately jump to "This is a nand gate" and "This is an inverter". Carefully go through each input and think about what happens when it's low or high. Alternatively, just make a big truth table (this will take a while) and figure out the output z for each combination of inputs. It may help to break the truth table into two smaller ones, one of both D and E with the output taken at the drain of D or E (I shall call it N), and the other one of A, B, C, and N

Comment: I see, I'll work on it and see what I get.

Comment: I tried what you said and I got 0100. What did I do wrong? @C_Elegans

Comment: Can't really tell what you did wrong if you don't show your work

Comment: So I caught my mistake and now I calculated 0001. Am I heading in the right path? @C_Elegans

Comment: You are correct that C will always be conducting and can just be replaced by a wire. However "If D or E is one then the unlabeled mosfet can be replaced by a wire" is wrong. Think about what happens to the voltage at the unlabeled mosfet's gate when D or E is conducting, and think about what inputs cause D and E to conduct.

Comment: What do you think now @C_Elegans ?

Answer (score 1):

No, your current guess of "0001" is still wrong.

Here are some hints to get you going:

- There are two separate logic functions here, one associated with each of the load resistors.
- One of those functions has inputs D and E. Call its output Y.
- The other function has inputs A, B, C and Y, and its output is Z.
- Start by working out the full truth table for Y (four entries).
- Then work out the full truth table for Z (16 entries).
- Finally, in your tables, find the four specific results asked for in the problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f43GJ7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you redraw the circuit like this, you will get more clarity. Then deduce Z as:

- Can you write the boolean expression for Z in terms of A,B,C,X ?
- After that, write the expression for X in terms of D and E.
- Substitute and reach the final expression for Z.